# DB2 problem loading Byte data type into DB2BulkCopy in C#

Tags: c#, db2, ado.net, db2-luw

I have a multi-database application where the user can specify different data types to be bulk loaded into tables. One such data type is the System.Byte data type. So essentially they specify that the DataColumn is of type Byte and it creates a new instance with:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(header, typeof(byte)));
```

This is not the exact code but this is essentially what it's doing. The database code then creates the most appropriate underlying column type. For DB2 this is SMALLINT, for MySQL it is tinyint unsigned, etc, etc. So a data type that can always at least hold the underlying type, in this case, System.Byte.

However, if I then attempt to load this DataTable in through DB2BulkCopy I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte' to type 'System.Byte[]'.'
```

This happens in the weeds of:

```
IBM.Data.Db2.dll!IBM.Data.Db2.DB2Parameter.MarshalToNative(ref IBM.Data.Db2.DB2ParamInfo paramInfo, int iArrayBindCount, byte prevCType) Line 2167
    at IBM.Data.Db2\DB2Parameter.cs(2167)
```

Now, I can get around this by making the DataColumn in the original code a System.Int16 rather than byte, but this breaks everything else. Any reason why DB2 can't handle a smaller subset data type like byte rather than short?

This is DB2 for Windows, version 11.5 and uses the very latest provider. 6.0.0.300.

**Update**

The following code example shows this problem:

```
using IBM.Data.Db2;
using System.Data;

var con = new DB2Connection("your connection string");
con.Open();
var dt = new DataTable("input");
dt.Columns.Add("INPUT_COL", typeof(byte));
dt.Rows.Add(6);

var copy = new DB2BulkCopy(con);
copy.DestinationTableName = "Table Name";
copy.ColumnMappings.Add("INPUT_COL", "NUMBER_COL");
copy.WriteToServer(dt);
con.Close();
```

This will throw the error but changing the DataTable column definition to:

```
dt.Columns.Add("INPUT_COL", typeof(short));
```

And it will work. Assuming a table with a single column of type SMALLINT.

Comment: The may be a Little Endian/Big Endian issue.

Comment: How would I get around that? Shouldn't the .net provider deal with that?

Comment: It look like the data is an array and not byte.  Try changing to dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(header, typeof(byte[])));

Comment: It’s not. It’s a byte. Simply changing it to short makes it work. The data is numbers between 0 and 255.